# Unable to write file in python

Tags: python

Probably a very noob question..

But
When I try:

```
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename),"w")
```

I get an error

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/path/filename'
```

Isnt it that since i have said "w" .. it will write a new file if its not there already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message can be reproduced like this:

```
import os
filename = '/home/path/filename'
f = open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename),"w")
f.close()

# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/path/filename'
```

The problem here is that `filename` is an absolute path, so
`os.path.join` ignores the first argument and returns `filename`:

```
In [20]: filename = '/home/path/filename'

In [21]: os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
Out[21]: '/home/path/filename'
```

Thus, you are specifying not only a file that does not exist, you are specifying a *directory* that does not exist. `open` refuses to create the directory.

Comment: @unutbu.. How do i resolve this? What i was thinking of achieving was.. no matter from where i execute the code.. the file will be saved in the right location on server?

Comment: @Fraz: Try defining `filename = 'filename'` rather than an absolute path. That will cause `os.path.join(..., filename)` to place the file in the same directory as the script.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to literally write `home/path/filename`? In that case, it's complaining that `/home/path` doesn't exist. Try creating a directory named `/home/path` or choosing a file name inside a directory that already exists (for example, find out what the path is to your actual home directory.) You can also use relative paths. See
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29
for the difference between absolute and relative paths.

Comment: HI. .Thanks for looking into my query.. home/path is there.. but just the filename is not there? thats what i am trying to write??